# Widgets aren't showing in Customizer wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I created custom Footer Areas for my Wordpress theme, where I included widgets. But in the Appearance->Customize->Widgets there aren't any of them. Searched for hours, no answers.

[Link to the picture](http://jaankoppe.planet.ee/images/widget.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends are u building your own widgets or using the  wp-widget-customizer plugin. If they were ever working and you have a backup try reverting back to previous version.Either way you can try

1. clearing your cache, cookies and browser history
2. Logout of wp and log back in again.
3. deactivate all plugins
4. please place this code on the desire page
5. create a footer.php file
6. Use a default wp theme like twentytwelve and follow the functions format, to use as your own.

try using this widget format

```
register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Footer', 'paste theme folder name or database name here' ),
        'id'            => 'footer-1',
        'description'   => '',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h4>',
    ) );
```

Comment: I have a footer.php file, my widgets are working on the footer area also, the only thing is, that they are not showing on the customizer area. This code did not help also.
PS. No need to use any customizer plug-in since 3.9 ?